# Facing Issue to make the UUID as endpoint in Django Rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, web, django-models, django-rest-framework

As I am new to Django I am unable to make the endpoint in API in the rest-framework library how to make the UUID as an EndPoint their

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

As For Serialize the data their

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id']
```

For View

```
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'pk:'
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
```

For Routing

```
from . import views
from pprint import print
from rest_framework_nested import routers



router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('products', views.ProductViewSet,basename='products'),   
router.register('collections', views.CollectionViewSet,basename='collections')
router.register('carts', views.CartViewSet, basename='carts')
pprint(router.urls)
```

How to Resolve this Error

```
[01/Jan/2022 14:47:48] "GET /store/carts/ HTTP/1.1" 405 17010
[01/Jan/2022 14:48:04] "POST /store/carts/ HTTP/1.1" 201 16991
[01/Jan/2022 14:48:15] "OPTIONS /store/carts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17589
Not Found: /store/carts/fc233c62-14dc-4cbe-a488-5add2c083b81
[01/Jan/2022 14:48:37] "GET /store/carts/fc233c62-14dc-4cbe-a488-5add2c083b81 HTTP/1.1" 404 16322`
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: please check again as you said i improve it

Answer (score 1):

`CartViewSet` inherits from `CreateModelMixin` and `GenericViewSet` so it doesn't implement the retrieve action.

You need to inherit from `RetrieveModelMixin` if you want to add this action to your viewset

```
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    ...
```